# Italics not working in WYSISYG

Tags: bug, formatting

In [this thread](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/7859/how-do-i-set-the-clock-speed-fuses-on-an-attiny85-when-using-an-arduino-as-a-pro/32958#32958), I gave an answer and attempted to use italics at the end of it but failed; rather, my text shows up with the markup asterisks about it but no formatting. (See for yourself.)

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It looks like the "_" (underscore) is what is causing it to fail. I added a little work around, but it isn't a "real" fix.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks. +1.